# charaterAtIndex Issues

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

What's wrong with this code.  I am trying to remove the leading zero from a String that contains the date.  The condition below seems to never be true.  Is this use of characterAtIndex correct?  Is there an alternative?

```
    // new_date = 01/26/11
    NSString *displayDate = [[NSString alloc] init];
    NSRange date_leading_zero = NSMakeRange (0,1);
    if([new_date characterAtIndex:0] == @"0")
 {
  displayDate = [new_date stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:date_leading_zero withString:@""]; 
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if([new_date characterAtIndex:0] == @"0")`

should be

`if([new_date characterAtIndex:0] == '0')`

`-characterAtIndex:` returns a `unichar` (a typedef for a 16-bit unsigned int) and not an `NSString`.

Answer (score 1):

`[new_date characterAtIndex:0]` returns an unsigned short, but `@"0"` is an `NSString`, so comparing them with `==` will essentially never succeed.  Use

```
if( [new_date characterAtIndex:0] == '0' )
```

instead.